# Proving that sum is invariant under bijections.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove the following: let $(G,+)$ be an abelian group, let $I_n^m = \{i \in \mathbb{N} : n \leq i \leq m\}$ and $I_r^k = \{i \in \mathbb{N} : r \leq i \leq k\}$. Let also $\varphi : I_n^m \to I_r^k$ be a bijection and $f : I_n^m \to G$ some arbitrary function. Then

$$\sum_{i =n}^{m}f(i)=\sum_{j=r}^{k}(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(j).$$

My attempt is as follows: since there's a bijection between $I_n^m$ and $I_r^k$, then the cardinality $\xi = |I_n^m| = |I_r^k|$. In that case, we shall prove by induction on $\xi$. In fact, if $\xi = 1$ we must have $n=m$ and $r=k$ and the only possible bijection $\varphi$ is $\varphi(n)=r$. In that case we have:

$$\sum_{i=n}^mf(i)=f(n)=f(\varphi^{-1}(r))=\sum_{j=r}^{k}(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(j).$$

Now, suppose the proposition is true for $\xi = \alpha$ we want to show that it is valid for $\alpha+1$. By construction of $I_n^m$ and $I_r^k$, adding one to the cardinality aims to get $I_n^{m+1}$ and $I_r^{k+1}$ as the sets we are working with. Let then $f : I_n^{m+1} \to I_r^{k+1}$ be the function being summed. We must have:

$$\sum_{i=n}^{m+1}f(i)=\sum_{i=n}^mf(i)+f(m+1)$$

On the sum from $n$ to $m$ only the values of $f$ at $I_n^m$ are important, so that we can replace $f$ by the restriction $f|_{I_n^m}$, then we have:

$$\sum_{i=n}^{m+1}f(i)=\sum_{i=n}^mf|_{I_n^m}(i)+f(m+1)$$

Now if $\varphi : I_n^{m+1}\to I_r^{k+1}$ is the bijection we are working with, we can also consider the restriction $\varphi|_{I_n^m}$, so that by the hypothesis of induction this is the same as:

$$\sum_{i=n}^{m+1}f(i)=\sum_{i=n}^m(f|_{I_n^m}\circ\varphi|_{I_n^m})(i)+f(m+1)$$

But this is a problem, because I cannot assure that $\varphi|_{I_n^m}$ is a bijection between $I_n^m$ and $I_r^k$. Indeed it can be a bijection between $I_n^m$ and some other proper subset of $I_r^{k+1}$. So I think this proof doesn't work. Is this proof on the right way or not?

I've thought on a simpler proof, but it's **so** simple, that it seems hard to be correct and rigorous. Indeed, the proof was: consider the sum with $\xi = n-m+1$ elements

$$\sum_{i=n}^mf(i) = f(n) + \cdots + f(m),$$

then since $\varphi$ is a bijection, there are $i_1, \dots, i_\xi \in I_r^k$ such that $\varphi(n)=i_1,\dots ,\varphi(m)=i_{\xi}$ so that the sum above is the same as:

$$\sum_{i=n}^m f(i)=f(\varphi^{-1}(i_1))+\cdots +f(\varphi^{-1}(i_\xi)),$$

and finally, since in abelian groups sum is associative and commutative in general and since the $i_1,\dots i_\xi$ are simply all the elements of $I_r^k$ we can rewrite this as the sum over all the elements of $I_r^k$ as:

$$\sum_{i=n}^m f(i)=\sum_{j=r}^k f(\varphi^{-1}(j)).$$

The second proof is much simpler, but I'm unsure on the part of rearranging the indexes and so on. Is this second proof better than the first one?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: When you increase the cardinality by one, not necessarily you will get the new set as the form $I_n^{m+1}$. For example, you can union the natural $2m$ to it. Maybe it is better to use induction on its length $m-n$.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer your second proof, and it is correct. The reason for my preference is that it gets right to the heart of the matter. In general, if $\varphi: I \to J$ is a bijection between finite $I,J \subset \mathbb{N}$ then $\varphi^{-1}(J) = I$, each $i \in I$ can be written as $i = \varphi^{-1}(j)$ for a unique $j \in J$, and $G$ abelian implies we may sum its elements in any order we wish. Thus
$$
\sum_{j \in J} f(\varphi^{-1}(j)) = \sum_{i \in \varphi^{-1}(J)} f(i) = \sum_{i\in I}f(i).
$$
This is just a slight generalization of what you've already said.